# Split up strings into RTF table cells and max total width

Tags: vb.net, class, rtf, cells

VB2010. May be a bit hard to understand but I have a list of classes and one field is a string message. I'm outputting these messages to an RTF document but want to maximize use of horizontal space so am trying to dynamically create a table and fit as many messages in one row as possible and then another row. This while I maintain a max width possible for a row.

```
Public Class TripInfo
    Public SysId As String = ""
    Public CreateDate As DateTime
    Public OutMessage As String = ""
    Public OutMessageWidth As Integer = 0 'the width of the message in char count up to first LF
End Class

Dim myTrips1 as New List(Of TripInfo)
Dim myTrips2 as New List(Of TripInfo)
```

So as I iterate through the lists I want to create rows that are themselves no longer than 45 characters. Something like:

```
---------------------------------------------
|"Message1 |"Message2 |"Much longer message |
| Trip1   "| Trip2"   | with two lines"     |
---------------------------------------------
|"message is even longer than the others"   |
---------------------------------------------
|"trip is ok |"trip was cancelled due to CW |
| enroute"   | must log to system"          |
---------------------------------------------
|"Message3 |"Message4 |"Message5 |"Message6"|
| Trip3   "| Error"   | Stop"    |          |
---------------------------------------------
```

*Note that the message itself can span more than 1 line with LFs to display a multi-line message

I have scratch code to write the RTF code for the tables and have substituted fake messages with multiple embedded LFs and the output looks good.

```
Dim sbTable As New StringBuilder
sbTable.Append("\pard \trowd\trql\trgaph108\trleft36\cellx1636\cellx3236\cellx4836\intbl R1C1\cell R1C2\cell R1C3\cell\row \pard")
sbTable.Append("\pard \trowd\trql\trgaph108\trleft36\cellx4642\intbl R1C1\cell\row \pard")
sbTable.Append("\pard \trowd\trql\trgaph0\trleft36\cellx4642\cellx5500\intbl R1C1\cell R1C2\cell\row \pard")
```

However I just cant seem to get my head around how to even start this to do it dynamically. It seems like I may need to do two iterations. One to break up the messages into rows and then another to actually write the RTF code.
I have so far pseudo code but need some help with my logic.

```
dim v as integer = 0 'total width of current row
For each t as TripInfo in myTrips1 and myTrips2
    if (t.OutMessageWidth added to v) > 45 then
      start new row and append
    else
      append to current row
    endif
Next t
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the properties of your `TripInfo` class, I'm going to have to make some assumptions. If any property I assume doesn't exist, you can either create it or modify the code to get the same effect.

```
Dim t As TripInfo, AllTrips As New List(Of TripInfo)
For Each t In myTrips1
    AllTrips.Add(t)
Next
For Each t In myTrips2
    AllTrips.Add(t)
Next
If AllTrips.Count > 0 Then
    For Each t In AllTrips
        Dim NewRow() As String = t.Lines
        Dim w As Integer = t.OutMessageWidth
        Dim h As Integer = t.Lines.Count
        For ItemHeight As Integer = h To 1 Step -1
            For Each CompareTrip As TripInfo In AllTrips
                If AllTrips.IndexOf(t) <> AllTrips.IndexOf(CompareTrip) _
                And CompareTrip.Lines.Count = ItemHeight _
                And w + CompareTrip.OutMessageWidth <= 45 Then
                    w += CompareTrip.OutMessageWidth
                    For l As Integer = 0 To h -1
                        NewRow(l) = NewRow(l).PadRight(w) & CompareTrip.Lines(l)
                    Next
                    AllTrips.Remove(CompareTrip)
                End If
            Next
        Next
        AllTrips.Remove(t)
        'Write lines of NewRow to your RTF
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Let me take some time to digest this. The only thing I see is that maybe I did not such a good job of relaying my idea as each box above is actually one cell in the table. Let me see if I can work with your sample and adjust as necessary.